# Python 2 member list to dict

Tags: python

I have a string of the form "Weather:getWeather", I need to convert this into a dict below

```
{
 "RemoteService": "Weather",
 "RemoteApi": "getWeather",
}
```

Currently this what I am doing

```
remote_service, remote_api = remote_signature.split(":")
service_metrics["RemoteService"] = remote_service
service_metrics["RemoteApi"] = remote_api
```

Although this might be okay, was curious as always is there a better pythonic way of doing it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dict` will accept a list of key-value tuples to generate a new dictionary.

```
keys = ['RemoteService', 'RemoteApi']
values = 'Weather:getWeather'.split(':')
service_metrics = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 2):

dictionary comprehension:

```
{ k:v for k,v in zip (  ['RemoteService', 'RemoteApi' ],
                         "Weather:getWeather".split( ':' ) ) }
```

Comment: Or alternatively: `{ k:v for k in ['RemoteService', 'RemoteApi'] for v in "Weather:getWeather".split( ':' ) }`

Answer (score 1):

Use json library:

```
import json

remote_signature = """{"RemoteService":"Weather","RemoteApi":"getWeather"}"""

remote_dict = json.loads(remote_signature)
```

Comment: I don't see why this is being upvoted so much. The OP's string isn't valid JSON. It might be possible to tack on curly braces on either side, depending on the string, but there's no reason to assume this is possible.